# getting null from property binded for selected wpf combobox value

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have class DimensionType, it has properties Name, Id, etc. I constructed Property in my ViewModel = "dimStyleId" to retrieve selected form ComboBox. I am getting null in this property although I checked it in TextBlock and get it.

```
<!--Dimension Type Combobox-->
        <ComboBox x:Name="DimensionType" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding  dimTypes , Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  SelectedValue="{Binding dimStyleId , Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectedValuePath="DimensionType"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  Padding="3"  />
```

and here is  my VM Class

```
 public class GridsDimViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ElementId dimensionType;

        private ElementId _dimStyleId { get; set; }
        public ElementId dimStyleId
        {
            get
            {
               return _dimStyleId;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_dimStyleId != value)
                {
                    _dimStyleId = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(dimStyleId));
                }
                

            }
        }
}
```

**and here is  my check textbox which gets the id in it**

```
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding dimStyleId}" 
                           Padding="3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Swap

```
SelectedValuePath="DimensionType"
```

to

```
SelectedValuePath="Id"
```